# moment.tz.guess() returning empty in Firefox

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

In Chrome browser the following code returns the current timezone as `Asia/Calcutta`, but in Mozilla Firefox it returns `undefined`.

```
console.log(moment.tz.guess());
```

Can any one tell me where may be the problem?.

Comment: Which version of Firefox, moment and moment-timezone are you using? It works for me using Firefox 5.1.0, moment 2.17.1 and moment-timezone 0.5.11

Comment: Firefox 44.0 , moment 2.10.6 ,moment-timezone 0.2.3. i think its better for me to update the moment and moment-timezone latest version and then need to check.

Comment: I too have the same issue in my firefox 96.0 (64-bit), Ubuntu 18.4, moment 2.24.0  moment-timezone 0.5.34. It is working fine for me.   The only thing I noticed is, For example, your app is opened in Chrome and Firefox, and your system time zone is IST.  So Changed time Zone to CST. Now I just refreshed the  Chrome, so Time is converted to CST.   But when I refreshed the FireFox, It's still showing IST only. If i open new my app in the new tab of Firefox it's working  OR if I closed and reopen the Firefox it's working fine.